# Funcion de busqueda Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, livewire

Alguien podria ayudarme con mi funcion, puede hacer busquedas por el numero de factura, pero necesito que haga busquedas por numero de factura mas el producto pór ejemplo teclear 1130 TPC0WJO, donde 1130 es el numero de la factura y TPC0WJO es el nombre del producto,
esta es mi funcion:

````
public function findFactura($recepcion) {
       return viewfacturaa::select(
           'FACTURA',
           'FECHA',
           'DENOMINACION_SOCIAL',
           'NOMBRE_COMPLETO',
           'CANTIDAD',
           'PRODUCTO',
           'DESCRIPCION_FACTURA',
           'MONEDA',
           'TC',
           'PRECIO_UNIDAD',
           'SUBTOTAL',
           'TOTAL_IVA'
       )
           ->where('FACTURA', '=', $recepcion)->get();
       } ```
````

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Espero que te sirva. No es necesario hacer un select de todos los campos, obteniendo el objeto entero tienes acceso a todo el contenido de la tabla.

```
public function findFactura($recepcion, $nombre_producto) {
           $factura = viewfacturaa::where('FACTURA', $recepcion)
               ->where('PRODUCTO', 'LIKE', '%'.$nombre_producto.'%')
               ->get();


            return $factura;
}
```

Comment: y para llamar a esa funcion como tendria que agregar la segunda variable

Comment: ```public function find()
    {
        $this->listRecepcion = $this->findFactura($this->recepcion->nombre_producto);

    }```

Answer (score 0):

````
public function findFactura($nrofactura, &nombreproducto) {
       return viewfacturaa::select(
           'FACTURA',
           'FECHA',
           'DENOMINACION_SOCIAL',
           'NOMBRE_COMPLETO',
           'CANTIDAD',
           'PRODUCTO',
           'DESCRIPCION_FACTURA',
           'MONEDA',
           'TC',
           'PRECIO_UNIDAD',
           'SUBTOTAL',
           'TOTAL_IVA'
       )
           ->where('FACTURA', '=', $nrofactura)
           ->where('PRODUCTO', 'like', &nombreproducto)
           ->get();
       } ```
````

Comment: si agrego otra variable como quedaria aqui

Comment: public function find()
    {
        $this->listRecepcion = $this->findFactura($this->recepcion);

    }